Are Jews allowed to practise usury?
The Bible strongly condemns usury:

(Ezek 18:13) gives on interest and takes usury - should he live? He
shall not live! He has committed all these abominations: he shall
surely be put to death, his blood shall be upon him.

But history has shown that Jews have very often and gladly practiced usury, especially against non-Jews. See some testimonies here:

Luther: "That is, they permit themselves and their subjects to be
abused and sucked dry and reduced to beggars with their own money,
through the usury of the Jews. For the Jews, as foreigners, certainly
should have nothing; and what they have certainly must be ours. They
do not work, do not earn anything from us, neither do we donate or
give it to them. Yet they have our money and goods and are lords in
our land where they are in exile. If a thief steals ten gulden he must
hang; if he robs people on the highway, his head is gone. But a Jew,
when he steals ten tons of gold through his usury, is dearer than God
Himself. And as a distinguishing mark, they strengthen their faith and
bitter hatred against us by saying among themselves: “Keep on, see how
God is with us and does not forsake His people in exile. We do not
work, we enjoy good, lazy days; the cursed Goyim must work for us, we
get their money; thereby we are their masters, they, however, our
servants. Keep on, dear Children of Israel, it will be better still!
Our Messiah will come if we thus continue and appropriate to
ourselves, by usury, the possessions of the heathen!”"
Pope Clement VIII: "All the world suffers from the usury of the Jews,
their monopolies and deceit. They have brought many unfortunate people
into a state of poverty, especially the farmers, working class people
and the very poor. Then, as now, Jews have to be reminded
intermittently that they were enjoying rights in any country since
they left Palestine and the Arabian desert, and subsequently their
ethical and moral doctrines as well as their deeds rightly deserve to
be exposed to criticism in whatever country they happen to live."

Now my question: Are Jews allowed to practise usury against non-Jews according to the Bible?

Anti-Semitic comments of long ago may or may not be accurate in describing what Jews do.  That said, what they do and what the Mosaic Law allows are not always the same.  Maybe a better place to ask would be "Mi Yodeva" (Judaism Stack Exchange)

I’m voting to close this question because this question would be better on Judaism SX

Other than that one out of context scripture, have you found anything in the Bible that condemns charging interest to Gentiles?

First we should clarify that "usury" in the Bible refers simply to lending money at interest, not to unethical lending at exorbitant rates. The Bible forbids Jews to lend money at interest to fellow Jews but not to gentiles.
Deuteronomy 23:21

From a foreigner you may demand interest, but you may not demand
interest from your kindred, so that the Lord, your God, may bless you
in all your undertakings on the land you are to enter and possess.

Conclusion. In terms of biblical teaching, Jews may lend money at interest to foreigners but not to fellow Jews. (However, modern Jews often do not follow this prohibition strictly, recognizing that lending money at interest to fellow Jews is helpful to the economy as long as the interest is reasonable.)

I wonder how that commandment should be understood in light of modern economics, where inflation means that the money is actually lent at a loss unless corresponding interest is charged. (E.g. you lend me enough money to buy 100 loaves of bread, and next year I repay you with enough money to buy only 96 loaves.)
